# How to determine if a value appears in a GROUP BY group

Tags: mysql

Given the table `foo`:

```
Num   Letter
------------
1     A
1     B
1     B
2     C
3     A
3     C
3     D
```

If I do `SELECT * GROUP BY Num` I of course get something like this:

```
Num   Letter
------------
1     A
2     C
3     A
```

What I'd like to refine this to is:

```
Num   Has_No_Letter_C
---------------------
1     Yes
2     No
3     No
```

There's probably a simple `SELECT IF ()` plus a `ORDER BY`, but I can't see it right now...

In my real-world example, the resultant table is `LEFT JOIN`ed to another table and I want to be able to reject the `No` entries but keep the `NULL`s if my other table `bar` has a `Num` = 4 row.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `SUM(condition)` within the `IF`:

```
SELECT   Num,
         IF(SUM(Letter = 'C'), 'Yes', 'No') AS Has_Letter_C
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY Num
```

Your `JOIN` then becomes:

```
SELECT   another_table.Num
FROM     another_table LEFT JOIN my_table ON another_table.Num = my_table.Num
GROUP BY another_table.Num
HAVING   my_table.Num IS NULL OR SUM(my_table.Letter = 'C') > 0
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one works. I changed the expression to `IF(SUM(Letter = 'C') = COUNT(Letter), 'Yes', 'No')` as my real-life example needs to check for all Cs, and I can apply that to get my full query working. (It's also probably time I refactored and normalised my tables...)

Comment: @KenY-N: To check if they're *all* `C`, it'd be simpler to lookup any value which is *not* C: `SUM(Letter <> 'C')`.

Answer (score 1):

If you `LEFT JOIN` the table to itself, you can easily determine if there are corresponding values or not.

This does the job if you take value "C" into account:

```
SELECT    t1.num, 
          IF(ISNULL(t2.num),"Yes","No") AS "Has_No_Letter_C"
FROM      yourtable AS t1
LEFT JOIN yourtable AS t2 ON t1.num=t2.num AND t2.`letter` = "C"
GROUP BY  num;
```